# Laravel Error: Maximum response size reached

Tags: php, laravel

Amigos, tengo un programa hecho en Laravel como backend, dentro de este hay un metodo que lee desde una tabla de la base de datos postgres,  los registros creados superan los 145.000 registros hasta el momento.

El metodo es el siguiente

```
public function list()
{
    $list = Cobus::orderBy('razon_social', 'desc')->orderBy('marca','desc')->get();
    return $this->getOk($list);
}
```

Pero al probar en postman obtento el error

> Error: Maximum response size reached

Como se podria solucionar este error o como recomiendan tratar cuando se tiene que listar muchos datos.

Answer (score 0):

Este error se debe a que el postman tiene un límite de tamaño para las respuestas que te trae, mayormente estos errores suceden cuando las peticiones que realizas son muy grandes (los datos mostrados en `JSON`). En el postman tenemos configurado por defecto el límite de tamaño a 50MB.

---

Puedes cambiar el valor del tamaño yendo a **Configuración** del Postman, ubícate en la pestaña **General** y modificas el valor predeterminado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, se soluciono lo de postman, pero ahora quisiera saber si recomendado tener unos request de esos tamaños para la apliccion web?

Comment: No es tan recomendable tener peticiones muy grandes, a menos que si hablamos de proyectos grandes o empresariales, en esos casos si se utilizarían.